# Tail files in a folder that are yet to be created

Tags: shell, tail

There are currently no log files in a dir, but I expect a log file to be created soon.  How do I start a tail on all these future files?

Edit: Removed the workaround I suggested.  It doesn't work as suggested in the comments.

Comment: That workaround doesn't work. The glob will be expanded to `abcd` and tail will monitor only that name. Do you know the name of the file that will be created ahead of time?

Comment: If you know the names of the files that will be created, then using `tail -F` instead of the lower case `-f` will continuously watch for creation of the file and also catch when it's removed and a new one started (for log rotation, etc.).